# Get all child nodes without cycles only recursion

Tags: functional-programming

Can someone provide me with pseudo code please? I can't use for, while etc. I can only call my functions.

Comment: You mean all child nodes of an arbitrary tree node?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all child nodes of an arbitrary binary tree node, you may do this:

```
(define (traverse node)
  (cond ((null? node) '())
        ((not (pair? node)) node)
        (else (cons (traverse (left-child node))
                    (traverse (right-child node))))))
```

For N-ary tree you could use kind of `get-child` functions instead of left and right child functions.

Comment: The built-in get-child function?

Comment: No, you should write it yourself. It depends on your own tree representation. For example, binary tree maybe represented as follows: `(list left-child right-child)`. So, the `left-child` is going to be `car`, and `right-child` is `cdr`